# Break the subfigure into two pages

Tags: floats, page-breaking, subfloats

I want to split the subfigure in figure into two pages. My first page is just contain two paragraph and after it, has empty spaces. So I want to split the figure into two pages. I try to give `\ContinuedFloat` and it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2b}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2c}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2d}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2e}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2f}
    \end{subfigure}

    \medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}\ContinuedFloat
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2g}
\end{subfigure}\hfil 
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2h}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2i}
\end{subfigure}

    \medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2j}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2k}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2l}
\end{subfigure}

    \caption{Manually Segmentation Tomatoes leaves.  (\subref{2a})-(\subref{2f}) healthy  leaves for $1^{\text{st}}$ data until $6^{\text{th}}$ data. (\subref{2g})-(\subref{2l}) leaves infected by disease for $1^{\text{st}}$ data until $6^{\text{th}}$ data.}
    \label{Gambar2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The result is

The first page:

[image]

The second page:

[image]

**I want**: The first page is

[image]

And the second page is

[image]

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the figure in two \begin{figure) and add `\ContinuedFloat` to the second one like I did. Is that what you wanted?

```
\documentclass[twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[skip=0.5ex]{subcaption}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-2]
    \begin{figure}[htbp]
    \centering 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2a}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2b}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2c}
    \end{subfigure}
    \medskip
    
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2d}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2e}
    \end{subfigure}\hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
        \subcaption{}
        \label{2f}
    \end{subfigure}
    \end{figure} %end first part of figure

    \medskip

    \begin{figure}\ContinuedFloat %begin second part of figure
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2g}
\end{subfigure}\hfil 
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2h}
\end{subfigure}\hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2i}
\end{subfigure}

    \medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2j}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2k}
\end{subfigure}\hfil % <-- added
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm,height=3cm]{example-image}
    \subcaption{}
    \label{2l}
\end{subfigure}


    \caption{Manually Segmentation Tomatoes leaves.  (\subref{2a})-(\subref{2f}) healthy  leaves for $1^{\text{st}}$ data until $6^{\text{th}}$ data. (\subref{2g})-(\subref{2l}) leaves infected by disease for $1^{\text{st}}$ data until $6^{\text{th}}$ data.}
    \label{Gambar2}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. Thank you Roland!